# Padrino development host

Tags: sinatra, padrino, rackup

How can I specify a default host and port for Padrino?

Normally I could start my process like this:

```
padrino start -h myhost
```

I want to change the default parameters of start. I expected that to be done by editing the config/apps.rb to:

```
Padrino.mount('MyApp::App', :app_file => Padrino.root('app/app.rb')).to('/').host('myhost')
```

However with the above line, Rackup still starts listening only on 'localhost'. So I assume that the host() option does not have an effect on Rack at all.

Ideally I would like to set the port/host just for "development" mode, but I cannot find the place where that setting is handed down to the rackup/webrick server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options are now defaulted to 127.0.0.1 for security and paranoid reasons.

To `rackup` here: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/28b014484a8ac0bbb388e7eaeeef159598ec64fc/lib/rack/server.rb#L187

To `padrino s` here https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/blob/5fe35ccbd2ffbf78d78233e9a47759eff1c6cc92/padrino-core/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb#L16

Considering your desire to host development mode app on local Ethernet, you have a dedicated server and you should have no problem setting up something like Passenger to host your app.

BTW, version `1.5.2` of `rack` still hosts the `config.ru` on `0.0.0.0`, if you are locked on this version you can use `rackup` to host your development app for local network.

Comment: oh perfect :(  so the paranoid default will not let me test my development server on mobile devices within my network

Comment: Yeah, I can relate. It's somehow considered a good practice to shield new developers from vague potential risks at the expense of usability and entry level.